# Finnesing fullcallendar; list view ordinals

Tags: javascript, datetime, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Upgrading to fullcalendar v5. Wonderful tool!
In list view I would like to have the left col display 'Friday 2nd' - or Sat 3rd... etc.
I have set

```js
listDayFormat: { weekday: 'long', day: 'numeric' },
```

and thought this would reverse the order of the default: "2 Friday" to Friday 2 (which I could mostly live with - but it does not change the order.
I have worked a hack - which works for my specific, (current) needs, but it is still a hack. In fc-list.min.js I declare an ordinal function at top

```js
function swap(thus) {
    x = thus.split(' ')[0]; // day number
    y = thus.split(' ')[1]; // day name
    var s=["th","st","nd","rd"], v=x%100;
        return y+' '+x+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}
```

Then in the min.js I call this function.

```js
<td class="'+(r.getClass("tableListHeading")||r.getClass("widgetHeader"))+'" colspan="3">'
+(i?t.buildGotoAnchorHtml(o,s,e,{class:"fc-list-heading-main"},
    //t.htmlEscape(s.format(e,i)) // original  

swap(s.format(e,i)) // function swap() set at page top  

  ):"")
+(a?t.buildGotoAnchorHtml(o,s,e,{class:"fc-list-heading-alt"},t.htmlEscape(s.format(e,a))):"")+"</td>")},
```

I have a fix - but not a solution.
Can anyone set me on a straighter path? Thank you.

Comment: The order depends on your locale...check the examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format

Comment: @ADyson - Thanks for the link You will have to allow my 'enthusiast programmer' limitations. How does this integrate with fullCal? I am currently exploring a 'eventRender: function(info)...' solution. PS - I was trying to figure the edit you made... add extra tags? thx

Comment: `How does this integrate with fullCal` ...fullCalendar just uses the built-in JS Date functionality to format any dates - although this can be overriden by using one of the available plugins, or by providing  a completely custom formatting function of your own. See  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting for the various options.

Comment: You can see the edit I made by viewing the question's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69442445/revisions) (it's also linked above - see where my name is and the bit saying "X hours ago"? Click that link to get there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dayHeaderContent` hook sets the content of the day header to a custom value. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-header-render-hooks

Example: https://codepen.io/stevewillson/pen/jOwgGqm

The below code can be used within a `FullCalendar` instance to set the day header content to "Friday 2nd", "Saturday 3rd"...

```
dayHeaderContent: function(info) {
    let s = '';
    // get the day of the month (number)
    const dayOfMonth = info.date.getDate();
    // set the ordinal value of the date in s
    if (dayOfMonth > 3 && dayOfMonth < 21) s = 'th';
    switch (dayOfMonth % 10) {
        case 1:  s = 'st'; break;
        case 2:  s = 'nd'; break;
        case 3:  s = 'rd'; break;
        default: s = 'th';   
    }
    const locale = 'en-US';
    // get the name of the day (Friday, Saturday ...)
    const dayName = info.date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' });
    return dayName + ' ' + dayOfMonth + s;
},
```

Comment: way cool. Thank you. I have a parallel issue - highlighting today in list view - and this line may allow me to do that. I have a few 'pots on the boil' so it may take me a few hours (day?) to test the limits of this approach. Cheers.

Comment: As an aside, you can use CSS to highlight the current day within fullCalendar ```/* highlight the current day */
.fc-day-today .fc-cell-shaded {
  background-color: yellow;
}```, I updated the example to show this.

Comment: Appreciate the attention. Replicated your set up. But, when I put my json for events... it doesn't work. When I try the js/css that you used (5.9) in my setup, nothing. I put dHC: function() {return 'toot'; } in your setup; OK. When I try in mine - nothing, not even console logs. I am using 4 so perhaps dHC was not added until 5? Conundrum... I upgraded from 1.5 to 4 (a bit of a struggle) do I revisit the pain again to 5.9? A bit of a non sequitur really :( - I will check dayHead inclusion - mark up your answer! PS thx for the .fc-day-today; also not showing in 4 - have a good 1. I'lBe back

Answer (score 0):

My original question was in relation to setting list header info. - specifically:

```js
      listDayFormat: { weekday: 'long', day: 'numeric' },
      listDayAltFormat: { year:'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' },
```

I might post this as another question but wanted to clarify my results and work with Steve's answer and adding a comment is far too limited. Steve pointed me at dayHeaderContent - which docs say "Generated content is inserted inside the inner-most wrapper of the header cell." - which is correct but it only allows a single, centered element. I was hoping to reproduce the left style of listDayFormat and right of listDayAltFormat. The only way I could think of was adding html. But it is not allowed. I experimented with varieties of >> eventContent: { html: '*some html*' } << but made no progress.
This is what I worked Steve's answer to...

```js
dayHeaderContent: function(info) {
   if (info.view.type == 'listMonth') {
   x = info.date.getDate(); // #dayOfMonth
        var s=["th","st","nd","rd"], v=x%100; // ordinal
        var ordinal = x+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
            // thought this would help with left/right setup
            // just a bit of fun
            var dayNames = ["Sun Day","Moon Day","Tiw's Day","Woden's Day","Thor's Day","Frige's Day","Saturn Day",];
      return dayNames[info.date.getDay()]+' '+ordinal; // getDay()=#dayOfWeek
        }
    },
```

and I did try numerous return permutations but feel at a dead end as regards my original aim. It is good enough for now.

Any additions to the original Q. would be most welcome. Thank you.